# Send Android cursor to Java Server

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an android.database.Cursor that I need to send via a socket to my server which is programed in java. The real question is that is there a way to import the library from android "cursor" to the java program.

Im opened to workarounds, the main issue is that I need to send the complete database which sits on my server to any android device that requests the database.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: A cursor is like describing a page number of a book. If I were the client, you were the server, and I told you, "page 87, 4th line of FooBook" where you did not have FooBook, then that cursor would likely have no semantic value to you. Send the entire resultset if you need to send all results.

Comment: Any idea how I can send the entire database. I know that's not the best solution since database could grow large, but my database wont be that big.